# Test web page on localhost without changing source paths

Tags: html, web

I have a webpage running on a server. It loads some resources which are included with paths relative to the current root (e.g. /folder1/partial.html).
When trying to open the webpage locally for testing, I run into problems because my Windows C: drive is now considered the current root. How can I work around this without having to change all the include paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple web server such as python SimpleHTTPServer solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

However, you can change your paths to be relative to the file rather than the root. This way it won't matter if you open your page locally or on the server. For instance:

```
root
|
+-- partial.html
|    
+-- some_folder
|  |  
|  +-- another_folder
|     |  
|     +-- some_file.html
```

If you wanted to reference partial.html inside some_file.html then it's relative path would be **../../partial.html**.

In English, this is saying go up two folders and then look for the named file.

Comment: This would work but I can explicitly not change the paths.